# WPF Converter casting causes Visual Studio designer exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

A converter such as what follows will cause the 2008 visual studio designer to not display the xaml, and error out with a "Specified cast is not valid." exception.

```
public class ItemsVisibilityToGridColumnWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //THE TWO OFFENDING LINES...
        var itemsVisibility = (Visibility)values[0];
        var orientation = (Orientation)values[1];

        if (orientation == Orientation.Horizontal && itemsVisibility != Visibility.Visible)
        {
            return new GridLength(0);
        }

        return new GridLength(4, GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Changing the cast to use a method such as this fixes the issue:

```
static class EnumCaster
{
    internal static Orientation CastAsOrientation(object value)
    {
        if (value is Enum)
        {
            return (Orientation)value;
        }
        return Orientation.Horizontal;
    }
    internal static Visibility CastAsVisibility(object value)
    {
        if (value is Enum)
        {
            return (Visibility)value;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

My question is, wtf is wrong with the Visual Studio designer?  And, is there a better way to cast these objects to their corresponding Enum in such a way that the designer doesn't throw a fit?

Comment: "wtf is wrong with the Visual Studio designer?"  I have a list, but this Internet is too small to contain it.

Comment: Could you post the XAML where you use this converter ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it might happen because at some point, the converter is called with bad arguments. You can debug the call the converter in the designer by following these steps :

- start a new instance of Visual Studio
- attach to the first VS instance (Tools -> Attach to process)
- open the converter source file
- put a breakpoint in the Convert method
- reload the WPF designer in the first VS instance

That way you should be able to examine the arguments passed to the converter

Comment: The designer is sending a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.  Thanks for the tip on debugging the designer.

Comment: Starting in Visual Studio 2012, the WPF Designer runs in a separate process named XDesProc.exe. You should attach to this process from the new instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I think the designer is processing the converter in the first example and is unable to cast because values[0] and values[1] are null.  If you do checks for null then this should resolve the problem.  The second example is essentially checking for null whilst using the "is" keyword.

Comment: Casting null to anything (reference type) doesn't throw an exception. The more likely reason is that values[0] and values[1] should be swapped around...

Comment: @Aviad, enums are not reference types, they are value types... casting null to a value type throws a NullReferenceException